# Chrome text issue : some text displayed midex

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, text

I have a problem with text in chrome Browser.
Some text displayed mixed.

> a short sample from the code

```
Css :
table.responsive { margin-bottom: 0; }

.pinned {
    position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; background: #fff; width: 35%; overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll; border-right: 1px solid #ccc; border-left: 1px solid #ccc; }
.pinned table { border-right: none; border-left: none; width: 100%; }
.pinned table th, .pinned table td { white-space: nowrap; }
.pinned td:last-child { border-bottom: 0; }

div.table-wrapper { position: relative; margin-bottom: 20px; overflow: hidden; border-right: 1px solid #ccc; }
div.table-wrapper div.scrollable table { margin-left: 35%; }
div.table-wrapper div.scrollable { overflow: scroll; overflow-y: hidden; }  

@media screen and (max-width: 960px) {

    table.responsive td, table.responsive th { position: relative; white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden; }
    table.responsive th:first-child, table.responsive td:first-child,
    table.responsive td:first-child, table.responsive.pinned td { display: none; }

}

  <table class="table responsive">
        <tr>
            <td>Kampanya Adı:</td>
            <td>@Model.Ad</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Kampanya Açıklaması :</label></td>
            <td>
                <div class="word-breaktxt">@Model.Aciklama</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
</table>
```

[image]

The some table tr td desing, but some text displayed bad.

Comment: could you please provide a 'replicable' example - as currently I can only guess you've used position:absolute badly somewhere.

Comment: No other code on the page...

I do not have this problem all the time, having this problem after some refresh only chrome browser. 

chrome versiyon : 40.0.2214.94